# Gregorio - Glyph missing?

Tags: luatex, luacode, directlua, gregorio

I've just updated to TexLive 2019 on Mac and then Gregorio 5.2.1.

This is the file I'm trying to compile (with my past distribution of TexLive 2018):

```latex
% !TEX program = LuaLaTeX+se
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% This is a simple template for a LuaLaTeX document using gregorio scores.

\documentclass[10pt]{book} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

% usual packages loading:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperheight=8.5in,
  paperwidth=5.5in,
  heightrounded,
}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\setmainfont [Ligatures=TeX]{Charis SIL}

\usepackage[debug]{gregoriotex} % for gregorio score inclusion
\usepackage{fullpage} % to reduce the margins
\gresetnabcfont{gregall}{9}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[spanish, latin, greek]{babel}

        \usepackage{afterpage}

        \newcommand\blankpage{
             \null
         \thispagestyle{empty}
         \addtocounter{page}{-1}
                \newpage
                }

\begin{document}


Los neumas tales como la virga: \GreNABCChar{vi} suelen encontrarse y leerse como  \GreNABCChar{ta}, \GreNABCChar{ta-}, \GreNABCChar{taSw}  de igual manera aparecen modificadas ya sea por la adición de letras o episemas como en:  \GreNABCChar{vi-}     \bigskip

\end{document}
```

But I got this error on compilation:

```
Module gregoriotex Error: 
(gregoriotex)             Glyph Flat was not found. on input line 37

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function <
...ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:108>
    (...tail calls...)
    ...xlive/texmf-local/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex.lua:1140: in field 're
set_score_glyph'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\greresetglyph ...iotex.reset_score_glyph([[#1]])}

l.37 \gresetglyphstyle{default}
                             %
?
```

I have reinstalled the whole thing twice, installed the supp_fonts-5_2_1.zip, runned luaotfload-tool with almost every option available and still the same result. I'm getting frustrated. Hope someone could help me. Thank you in advance

**Update** I have removed the gregoriotex in texmf-local, but the problem persists this is the log file:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=lualatex 2020.2.12)  12 FEB 2020 12:32
 system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**PruebaSemiotica.tex
(./PruebaSemiotica.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic-dev/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2020-01-26.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontl
oader-2020-01-26.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 4
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.11”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 5
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic-dev/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2020-02-11>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count163
\c@chapter=\count164
\c@section=\count165
\c@subsection=\count166
\c@subsubsection=\count167
\c@paragraph=\count168
\c@subparagraph=\count169
\c@figure=\count170
\c@table=\count171
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-02-11 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count172
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2020-02-08 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count173
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count174
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count175
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count176
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/03 v2.7h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2020/02/03 2.7h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (/
usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2020/02/03 v2.7h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count187
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/01/25 v2.0m Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2020/01/28 v0.5q Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count188
\calc@Bcount=\count189
\calc@Adimen=\dimen138
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen139
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count190
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2018/04/12 v2.0h eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen140
\Gin@req@width=\dimen141
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen142
\AM@pageheight=\dimen143

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def
File: ppluatex.def 2020/01/28 v0.5q Pdfpages driver for LuaTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box46
\AM@global@opts=\toks15
\AM@pagecnt=\count191
\AM@toc@title=\toks16
\c@AM@survey=\count192
\AM@templatesizebox=\box47
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty
Package: fullpage 1999/02/23 1.1 (PWD)
\FP@margin=\skip52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count193
\Gm@cntv=\count194
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count195
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen144
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen145
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen146
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen148
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen149
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen151
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "CharisSIL/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'CharisSIL(0)' created for font 'Charis
(fontspec)             SIL' with options [Ligatures=TeX,Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"CharisSIL:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;"

(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"CharisSIL:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+
smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"CharisSIL/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig
;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"CharisSIL/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"CharisSIL/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig
;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"CharisSIL/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig
;+smcp;"


(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex.sty
Package: gregoriotex 2019/04/06 v5.2.1 GregorioTeX system.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count196
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable5
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable6
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luamplib/luamplib.sty
Package: luamplib 2019/12/11 v2.20.4 mplib package for LuaTeX
Lua module: luamplib 2019/12/11 2.20.4 Lua package to typeset Metapost with LuaT
eX's MPLib.
\mplibtmptoks=\toks18
\everymplibtoks=\toks19
\everyendmplibtoks=\toks20
\mplibscratchbox=\box48
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count197
\decimalpart=\count198
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-main.tex

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-common.t
ex)
\gre@attr@dash=\attribute6
\gre@attr@center=\attribute7
\GreScoreId=\attribute8
\gre@attr@glyph@id=\attribute9
\gre@attr@glyph@top=\attribute10
\gre@attr@glyph@bottom=\attribute11
\gre@attr@syllable@id=\attribute12
\gre@atletter=\catcodetable7
Lua module: gregoriotex 2019/04/06 5.2.1 GregorioTeX module.
Custom whatsit marker = 1
Module gregoriotex Info: marker whatsit id is 1 on input line 131

(PruebaSemiotica.gaux)
Inserting `gregoriotex.write_greaux' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
\gre@gaux=\write3
\gre@read@temp=\read2
\gre@factor=\count199

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-spaces.t
ex
\gre@hyphenpenaltysave=\count266
\gre@exhyphenpenaltysave=\count267
\gre@doublehyphendemeritssave=\count268
\gre@finalhyphendemeritssave=\count269
\gre@brokenpenaltysave=\count270
\gre@loosenesssave=\count271
\gre@tolerancesave=\count272
\gre@pretolerancesave=\count273
\gre@emergencystretchsave=\skip53
\gre@widowpenaltysave=\count274
\gre@clubpenaltysave=\count275
\gre@saved@parskip=\skip54
\gre@saved@lineskip=\skip55
\gre@saved@baselineskip=\skip56
\gre@saved@lineskiplimit=\skip57
\gre@dimen@textlower=\dimen152
\gre@dimen@stafflinewidth=\dimen153
\gre@dimen@linewidth=\dimen154
\gre@dimen@stafflineheight=\dimen155
\gre@dimen@interstafflinespace=\dimen156
\gre@dimen@stafflinediff=\dimen157
\gre@dimen@constantglyphraise=\dimen158
\gre@dimen@staffheight=\dimen159
\gre@skip@syllablefinalskip=\skip58
\gre@skip@minTextDistance=\skip59
\gre@skip@minNotesDistance=\skip60
\gre@dimen@curTextDistance=\dimen160
\gre@dimen@curNotesDistance=\dimen161
\gre@skip@minShiftText=\skip61
\gre@skip@minShiftNotes=\skip62
\gre@dimen@bolshift=\dimen162
\gre@dimen@bolextra=\dimen163
\gre@dimen@clefwidth@current=\dimen164
\gre@dimen@clefwidth@largest=\dimen165
\gre@dimen@clefwidth@bol=\dimen166
\gre@dimen@eolshift=\dimen167
\gre@dimen@glyphraisevalue=\dimen168
\gre@dimen@additionalbottomspace=\dimen169
\gre@dimen@additionaltopspace=\dimen170
\gre@dimen@additionaltopspacealt=\dimen171
\gre@dimen@additionaltopspacenabc=\dimen172
\gre@saved@dimen@additionalbottomspace=\dimen173
\gre@saved@dimen@additionaltopspace=\dimen174
\gre@saved@dimen@additionaltopspacealt=\dimen175
\gre@saved@dimen@additionaltopspacenabc=\dimen176
\gre@saved@dimen@currenttranslationheight=\dimen177
\gre@saved@dimen@textlower=\dimen178
\gre@saved@dimen@currentabovelinestextheight=\dimen179
\gre@saved@dimen@constantglyphraise=\dimen180
\gre@space@count@additionaltopspacethreshold=\count276
\gre@space@count@additionaltopspacealtthreshold=\count277
\gre@space@count@additionaltopspacenabcthreshold=\count278
\gre@space@count@noteadditionalspacelinestextthreshold=\count279
\gre@dimen@textaligncenter=\dimen181
\gre@dimen@enddifference=\dimen182
\gre@dimen@previousenddifference=\dimen183
\gre@dimen@currenttranslationheight=\dimen184
\gre@skip@nextbegindifference=\skip63
\gre@dimen@annotationtrueraise=\dimen185
\gre@dimen@commentarytrueraise=\dimen186
\gre@skip@bar@requirement=\skip64
\gre@skip@bar@allocation=\skip65
\gre@dimen@bar@shift=\dimen187
\gre@skip@text@requirement=\skip66
\gre@skip@text@allocation=\skip67
\gre@dimen@text@shift=\dimen188
\gre@dimen@adjustedpreviousenddifference=\dimen189
\gre@skip@adjustednextbegindifference=\dimen190
\gre@skip@punctummorashift=\skip68
\gre@skip@alterationshift=\skip69
\gre@dimen@begindifference=\dimen191
\gre@dimen@lastglyphwidth=\dimen192
\gre@dimen@notesaligncenter=\dimen193
\gre@dimen@additionalleftspace=\dimen194
\gre@dimen@initialwidth=\dimen195
\gre@dimen@currentabovelinestextheight=\dimen196
\gre@dimen@temp@one=\dimen197
\gre@dimen@temp@two=\dimen198
\gre@dimen@temp@three=\dimen199
\gre@dimen@temp@four=\dimen256
\gre@dimen@temp@five=\dimen257
\gre@skip@temp@one=\skip70
\gre@skip@temp@two=\skip71
\gre@skip@temp@three=\skip72
\gre@skip@temp@four=\skip73
\gre@count@temp@one=\count280
\gre@count@temp@two=\count281
\gre@count@temp@three=\count282
\gre@space@count@newlinepenalty=\count283
\gre@space@count@nobreakpenalty=\count284
\gre@space@count@endofwordpenalty=\count285
\gre@space@count@endofsyllablepenalty=\count286
\gre@space@count@endafterbarpenalty=\count287
\gre@space@count@endafterbaraltpenalty=\count288
\gre@space@count@finalpenalty=\count289
\gre@space@count@endofelementpenalty=\count290
\gre@space@count@hyphenpenalty=\count291
\gre@space@count@brokenpenalty=\count292
\gre@space@count@looseness=\count293
\gre@space@count@tolerance=\count294
\gre@space@count@pretolerance=\count295
\gre@space@count@widowpenalty=\count296
\gre@space@count@clubpenalty=\count297
\greconffactor=\count298
)
\gre@box@temp@width=\box49
\gre@box@initial=\box50
\gre@biginitial=\count299
\gre@knownline=\count300
\gre@box@annotation=\box51
\gre@box@add=\box52
\gre@box@old=\box53
\gre@count@annotationvalign=\count301
\gre@box@commentary=\box54
\gre@box@lines=\box55
Module gregoriotex Info: Registering variant font greciliae as gre@font@variant@
A. on input line 993
Module gregoriotex Info: Registering variant font greciliae-hollow as gre@font@v
ariant@B. on input line 993
Module gregoriotex Info: Registering variant font greciliae-hole as gre@font@var
iant@C. on input line 993
Module gregoriotex Info: Mapping font greciliae on input line 998
Module gregoriotex Info: Mapping font greciliae-hollow on input line 998
Module gregoriotex Info: Mapping font greciliae-hole on input line 998

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-chars.te
x
\gre@box@hep=\box56
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-signs.te
x...ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: 
Module gregoriotex Error: 
(gregoriotex)             Glyph Flat was not found. on input line 37

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function <.
..ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:108>
    (...tail calls...)
    ...e/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex.lua:1140: in field 'res
et_score_glyph'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\greresetglyph ...iotex.reset_score_glyph([[#1]])}

l.37 \gresetglyphstyle{default}
                             %
? x


Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 17019 strings out of 481366
 100000,662416 words of node,token memory allocated 413 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 dir, 3 kern, 2 glyph, 5 attribute, 51 glue_spec, 5 attribu
te_list, 1 write, 1 user_defined, 1 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:7,3:2,5:7,7:1,9:3
 33900 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 38 fonts using 10997475 bytes
 43i,0n,78p,642b,239s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.

PDF statistics: 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: at first clean up and shorten your code. Stuff like inputenc, ucs,  type1cm  should not be used with lualatex. And other packages are not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Done, compiled just like it is now, but I got the same error.

Comment: Remove the gregoriotex in texmf-local so that the one from texlive 2019 is used. If the problem persists show the complete log-file.

Comment: It's persistent now, I have edited the question with the resultant log file

Comment: Hm. I have no problem on windows and I can't see in the log some relevant difference. Try to delete the luatex-cache in `\texlive\2019\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic`. Perhaps you have some faulty files there from your earlier tries.

Comment: This is very strange I have deleted that files, but the only difference was luaotfload building again the database but at the end I got the exact same error.

Comment: Did you also delete the fonts folder in the cache?

Comment: Yes, I did It again now but same error. :(

Comment: What happens if you compile `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}
\font\test={file:gregall.ttf}\test \char58368 \end{document}`

Comment: Compiles!, but I think the error is pointing other file somewhat like a character definition I guess

Comment: Does `\font\test={greciliae}\test \char 57398` works too? (that is the font with the missing Flat in it).

Comment: It doesn't compile last part of the error says: `</Users/fergilb/Library/Fonts/greciliae.ttf
! error:  (file /Users/fergilb/Library/Fonts/greciliae.ttf) (type 2): there are
 no glyphs in the subset
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: Ah, there is the problem. You have a local version of the font in /Users/fergilb/Library/Fonts/greciliae.ttf and this hasn't the needed glyphs. Remove it (and perhaps then also its lua/luc in the luatex-cache).

Comment: Thank you so much! Works neat now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary from the discussion in the comments

```
 (gregoriotex)             Glyph Flat was not found. on input line 37
```

means that a glyph from greciliae.ttf could not be found.

Testing the font and the glyph with

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \begin{document} 
   \font\test={greciliae}\test \char 57398 
 \end{document}
```

showed that a local font was used:

```
  /Users/fergilb/Library/Fonts/greciliae.ttf
```

Removing the font resolved the problem.